# how to determine restart policy of docker containers when name is empty?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I use docker-compose stop to shut down containers, but they come back later, you can see from docker ps output, here is the policy:

"RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },

when Name is "", what is the restart policy?

Thanks,

Comment: did you try docker inspect "container_name" or id

Comment: turn out it was started by a hourly cron job, sorry

Comment: Is the problem solved now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moreover whatever the restart policy is you can update the restart policy of the existing container with

```
docker update --restart=unless-stopped my-container
```